# Deleting image from Camera Roll and Photo Stream at the same time?

Tags: photo-stream, macos, camera

Now that Photo Stream lets you delete pictures, I find myself frequently deleting pictures from both Photo Stream and the Camera Roll manually. Is there any way to easily delete the same picture from both locations at once?

Answer (score 1):

The [iCloud FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5125) states that:

> Copies of Photo Stream photos you have saved to your Camera Roll on an iOS device, or imported into events in your iPhoto or Aperture library, will not be deleted when you delete photos from Photo Stream.

I guess it cant be done, at least *officially*.

Pictures in Photo Stream will be deleted after 30 days, though.

Comment: Hmm... I have pictures in my Photo Stream that are way older than 30 days.

Comment: Well, it should, as stated, in the iCloud FAQ: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486 You should try reseting it, though. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4890

Comment: I believe the Photo Stream FAQ should be interpreted like so: Photos will be removed from the syncing back-end of Photo Stream after 30 days, making them unavailable for syncing. For photos that *have* synced, iOS devices will keep 1000 photos in their Photo Stream storage, while Macs will keep an unlimited number.